# How to initialize member-struct in initializer list of C++ class?

Tags: c++, list, constructor, struct, initializer

I have the following class definitions in c++:

```
struct Foo {
  int x;
  char array[24];
  short* y;
};

class Bar {
  Bar();

  int x;
  Foo foo;
};
```

and would like to initialize the "foo" struct (with all its members) to zero in the initializer of the Bar class. Can this be done this way:

```
Bar::Bar()
  : foo(),
    x(8) {
}
```

... ?

Or what exactly does the *foo(x)* do in the initializer list?

Or is the struct even initialized automatically to zero from the compiler?

Comment: Note that members should be listed on initialization list in the same order as they are declared, while you declare `x` first but have it second on initialization list.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, you should (must !) read this [c++ faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) regarding POD and aggregates. In your case, `Foo` is indeed a POD class and `foo()` is a **value initialization** :

> To value-initialize an object of type
>   T means:
>
> - if T is a class type (clause 9)    with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor
>     for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a non-union class type    without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
> - if T is an array    type, then each element is    value-initialized;
> - **otherwise, the    object is zero-initialized**

So yes, foo will be zero-initialized. Note that if you removed this initialization from `Bar` constructor, `foo` would only be **default-initialized** :

> If no initializer is specified for an
>   object, and the object is of (possibly
>   cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or
>   array thereof), the object shall be
>   default-initialized; if the object is
>   of const-qualified type, the
>   underlying class type shall have a
>   user-declared default constructor.
>   **Otherwise, if no initializer is
>   specified for a nonstatic object, the
>   object and its subobjects, if any,
>   have an indeterminate initial
>   value**;

Comment: What if foo was defined as a const member?

Answer (score 10):

In standard C++ you need to make a ctor for Foo.

```
struct Foo {

  Foo(int const a, std::initializer_list<char> const b, short* c)
    : x(a), y(c) {
    assert(b.size() >= 24, "err");
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.begin() + 24, array);
  }

  ~Foo() { delete y; }

  int x;
  char array[24];
  short* y;
};

class Bar {

  Bar() : x(5), foo(5, {'a', 'b', ..., 'y', 'z'},
    new short(5)) { }

  private:

  int x;
  Foo foo;
};
```

In C++0x you may use uniform initialization list, but still you need dtor for Foo:

```
class Bar {

  Bar() : x(5), foo{5, new char[24]{'a', 'b', ..., 'y', 'z'},
    new short(5)} { }
  ~Bar() { delete[] foo.array; delete foo.y;}
  }
  private:

  int x;
  Foo foo;
};
```

To default initialize `foo` (as `Bar() : foo(), x(8) { }`) you need to give Foo a default ctor.

Comment: This is a bit unclear where you use C++03 vs C++0x. IIRC `initializer_list` is part of c++0x. Besides in your second codeblock you created two memory leaks.

Comment: now you have one double deletion (`foo.y`) and one memory leak (from the `new char[24]`, besides, I am not sure (but I might be wrong here) that this is the way to use `initializer_list`)

Comment: Had similar case, but `struct Foo {int x,y; }`, `struct Goo : Foo { int z; }`, `struct Boo { Foo fs[2]; int x; }` and static const array of Boos with initializer list `static const Boo boos[]  = { {{foo1, foo2},11}, {{foo3, foo6},15} }`
Dilemma to init like this: `struct Goo(int x, int y) : Foo(x,y)`, I'd need a ctor for Foo, but can not use non-aggregate (ctor) in initializer list...