# Correct way to initialize custom struct object in a class constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, initialization

In the constructor for myClass, in the code below, I initialize `ms` with `ms({4,5})`.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
 private:
  struct myStruct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
  };

public:
  myStruct ms;
  myClass() : ms({4,5}){} // This is where I initialize ms!
};

int main(){
  myClass mc;
  std::cout << mc.ms.val1 << " " << mc.ms.val2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
};
```

However, we are in the member initialization list, so the arguments to `ms` are the arguments to the ms's constructor. What happens here,
  essentially, is that we use the so-called "list initialization" to
  create an unnamed (anonymous) `myStruct` object: "{4,5}", and then we
  pass that object to the constructor of `ms`. So in principle, the
  anonymous intermediate object is created, copied to initialize `ms`,
  and then destroyed (although I'm pretty sure that the compiler knows
  better and initializes `ms` directly; but there is still the
  semantic difference). I was told that, instead of `ms({4,5})` I could simply do

```
ms(4,5)
```

and avoid making an intermediate object. However, when I do this, I get the following output:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall temp.cpp -o temp
temp.cpp: In constructor ‘myClass::myClass()’:
temp.cpp:12:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘myClass::myStruct::myStruct(int, int)’
   myClass() : ms(4,5){}
                     ^
temp.cpp:5:10: note: candidate: myClass::myStruct::myStruct()
   struct myStruct {
          ^
temp.cpp:5:10: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
temp.cpp:5:10: note: candidate: constexpr myClass::myStruct::myStruct(const myClass::myStruct&)
temp.cpp:5:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
temp.cpp:5:10: note: candidate: constexpr myClass::myStruct::myStruct(myClass::myStruct&&)
temp.cpp:5:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
makefile:15: recipe for target 'temp' failed
make: *** [temp] Error 1
```

So, to be clear, I am wondering what the best practice is, in terms of initialising a struct object in a class constructor. All help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203010/how-to-initialize-member-struct-in-initializer-list-of-c-class

Comment: Thank you @dmi. This gave me some insight, however it did not seem to answer my question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was told that, instead of `ms({4,5})` I could simply do `ms(4,5)`

That's almost right, but not quite. What you can actually do is `ms{4,5}`, that is, use direct-list-initialisation for the member `ms`. That way, it will use normal list initialisation rules, which in your case will invoke aggregate initialisation.

In other words, the member `ms` will be initialised directly in-place, without creating any temporary objects of type `myStruct`.

Comment: Thank you @Angew! Does this make sure that I am not using unnecessary any intermediate object?

Comment: I personally don't recommend this way of initialization as in my opinion it is very risk prone, even in spite it is supported by C++11 standard. As per my personal taste is better to provide a constructor to the struct and initialize it as `ms()`.

Comment: @JCKaz Yes, it guarantees that. I've changed the wording to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Angew You my friend, deserve a cookie! Thank you so much!